# Payment subscription - test callback

Tags: facebook, payment

We're currently looking at implementing Facebooks new [subscription payments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/subscriptions/). We already have a working payment setup for Facebook, and the callback url is set correctly. If I make regular test payment the callback is called correctly.

The setup for testing subscriptions is according to [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/subscriptions/#testusers). But either if I choose the always success or always fail there is no callback made to the payments callback url.

It does return an object that says the subscription is active an has an ID.

```
{status: "active", subscription_id: 204626XXXXXX}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook subscriptions are not regular purchase.

You will have to **setup Real time updates on 'payment_subscriptions'** object and listening to those available fields: ('status', 'pending_cancel', 'payment_status', 'last_payment'). See the documentation : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/subscriptions/, there is a section called "Consuming Real time updates"

Each time an user subscribes or cancel (or an implicit renew), you will be hit with the related subscription id. You can then ask the Graph API about this subscription object.

You can also retrieve the list of subscriptions for any user via the Graph Api call on '/payment.subscriptions'

All these calls have to be performed with an App access token.

I must confess this process is quite annoying if you always performed "synchronous" purchases. I did implement subscriptions, this was a loooooong & painful travel  ;)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible you only get a request sent to the callback URL if the subscription state changes, and you already have an active subscription for the user? I would think you would get a client-side error in this case, but I don't see any evidence that there's an error code for that.

What happens if you make a regular test payment multiple times for the same account?

Comment: Just tried to cancel an active subscription, which succeeded. But still no callback is being made. If I make a regular test payment the callback is made, and making multiple payments results in the same every time.

Answer (score 0):

Subscriptions are mapped to OpenGraph objects on Facebook side, as well as virtual currency, so, I suspect there is no callback made to server side, all that you can do is make some kind of http post (through a form, for example) insde the FB.ui callback and implement the doPost method in a Servlet. That's would be a way to get subscription information into some data source.

Edit: concerning to [payments callback](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/callback/), those items which order information are calculated based on OG object, facebook doesn't send a payments_get_items request, so there is no way to get order information after subscription creation. On the other hand, it could be possible that you receive some payments_status_update in the correspondent servlet (I'm talking about servlets because I'm a Java programmer, but the general idea applies for whichever technology you choose)